# How to to check if confirmed password is same as the first password in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having trouble validating if the entered password is same as confirmed password. It doesnt show the text message if it isnt the same or if it is same. It only shows the notice that the password field is empty?

HTML

```
<div>
  <label>Geslo:</label>
  <input type="password" id="myInput2" oninput="myFunction2()" name="password" id="koda"><br />
  <p id="demo2"></p>

</div>
<div>
  <label>Ponovi geslo:</label>
  <input type="password" name="repassword" oninput="myFunction3()" id="myInput3"><br />
  <p id="demo3"></p>
</div>
```

JS

```
function myFunction2() {
  var mediumRegex = new RegExp("^(((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]))|((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])))(?=.{6,})");
  if (m.value === "") {
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Prosim vnesite vaš geslo!";
    return false;

  } else if (mediumRegex.test(m.value) == false) {
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Geslo mora vsebovati vsaj eno veliko začetnico in številko!(Min.6 znakov)";
    return false;

  } else if (mediumRegex.test(m.value) === true) {
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "";
    return true;

  }
}

function myFunction3() {
  if (n.value === "" || n.value == NULL) {
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = "Prosim ponovno vnesite vaše geslo!";
  } else if (n.test(m.value) === false) {
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = "Vaše geslo se ne ujema!";

  } else if (n.test(m.value) === true) {
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = "Vaše geslo se  ujema!";

  }
}
```

Comment: `myFunction3()` was missing a closing `}`. The `div`s in the HTML were also missing valid opening and closing tags. It may have been that these errors occurred when you copied the code into stackoverflow, so I have proposed an edit removing the issues and improving the code formatting, but maybe check that this was not causing the original problem as well.

Comment: `m` and `n` (and `NULL`) are nowhere defined. Since you call `test` on `n`, is it a regular expression? Where in the code did you attempt to compare the two input values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I assume the variables `m` and `n` refer the input elements `#myInput2` and `#myInput3`.*

---

When I run your code I got two errors:

**1. `NULL` is not defined**

In JavaScript, `NULL` is `null`. (I guess it's just a typo tho)

**2. `n.test is not a function`**

It seems you are consued with value and element. Since I assume the `n` refers the input `#myInput3`, it is a HTMLElement which doesn't have `.test()` method. `.test()` is a method of RegExp. For this case, you could compare the two string without RegExp like below.

```js
function myFunction3() {
  if (n.value === "" || n.value == null) {
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = "Prosim ponovno vnesite vaše geslo!";
  } else if (n.value !== m.value) {
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = "Vaše geslo se ne ujema!";

  } else if (n.value === m.value) {
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = "Vaše geslo se  ujema!";

  }
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dxnmw4v0/

Answer (score 0):

Trivial example just to check if fields are equal.

```
isPasswordConfirmed = () => {
  if($('input.password').val() == $('input.passsword-confirmation').val()) {
    return true
  }
  return false
}
```

Make sure to classes 'password' and 'password-confirmation' to the inputs

Usage:

```
if(isPasswordConfirmed()) {
  // ... do something
} 
else {
 //
}
```